# Check if an event is ongoing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a collection of events in my Firestore database where each one has a `startDate` and an `endDate`. On client side I would like to query for events that are happening right now. Normally, you would just check if `currentDate` is inside the time interval, however this can't be done with Firestore since it is disallowed to have more than one comparison query.

Has anyone encountered this problem and how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

I you are storing the `startDate` and `endDate` as milliseconds, you could just take your client time in milliseconds and make a query against your events to know if it has already started, is ongoing or is done.

Personally I usually store dates in millis to make queries and also in a human readable format when I check the documents using the Console.

Comment: Ideally I would like to query for just the ongoing events. Your method is the one I'm using right now, but I imagine it won't scale very well.

Answer (score 0):

> however this can't be done with Firestore since it is disallowed to have more than one comparison query

No, you can query a Firestore collection using multiple comparison functions but **only** on the same property and **not** on multiple properties as you intend to do. According to the official documentation regarding [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> **Query limitations**
>
> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - Queries with range filters on different fields, as described in the previous section.

So as you have probably noticed, Cloud Firestore allows a range filter on a single field. The most reasonable explanation is that Firestore cannot guarantee its performance in such a case.

To solve this, you'll have to query your collection twice and combine the results of those queries on the client. It's not perfect since you need to query twice, but I think it will do the trick.